# Slow query time with Postgres 10 inside Docker vs bare-metal for AWS Linux 2

Tags: postgresql, performance, amazon-web-services, docker

I've been trying to deploy Postgres within Docker for portability reason, and noticed that query performance as measured by **"explain analyze"** has been painfully slow compared to bare metal.

For a table with **1.7 million rows**, a query on bare metal Postgres takes about **1.2 sec vs 4.8 sec on Dockered Postgres, an increase of 4 times!** This comparison is done with the same mounted volume for both bare-metal and Docker (for Docker, I'm using the `-v` option) The volume is a gp2 volume, mounted through AWS console, 60GB

Couple of things I tried:

1. Increase shared memory buffer option in postgresql.conf, which has negligible effect
2. Tried several volume mapping options (delegated, cached, consistent)
3. Upgrading Docker from 17.06-ce to 17.12-ce

This is all done in AWS Linux 2 instance. At this point I’m hoping to get more suggestions on what to do to improve performance.

**The docker run command I use:**

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 --name postgres -v /vol/pgsql/10.0/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:latest
```

Comment: What Docker storage driver are you using? If you're not sure, post the output of `docker info`. If Docker is configured to use the devicemapper driver on loopback devices, that might explain some of the performance degradation.

Comment: So i ran `docker info` and this is the storage driver I got `Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
` I'm assuming this is not the devicemapper one? Thanks.